# Error when trying to recover object from database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

According to Symfony2 documentation, I can access to instances in database with the next code:

```
public function showAction($id)
{
$producto = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository(’AcmeGuardaBundle:Producto’)
->find($id);
$nombreCategoria = $producto->getCategoria()->getNombre();
// ...
}
```

However, I try to do:

```
$imagen = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getRepository(’MSDHomeBundle:Imagen’)
               ->find($_SESSION['id']);
```

and I get the next error in the browser:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/src/MSD/HomeBundle/Controller/HomeController.php on line 219
```

What am I doing wrong? Imagen is a class stored in database, and persisting data works right.

Comment: Those are some weird quotes you're using... Are you getting the parser error in both cases, or only when using `$_SESSION['id']`?

Comment: Why you access the $_SESSION direct?

Comment: Oh, man! weird quotes was causing it. That is because I used copy paste.

Comment: @ManoloSalsa's... what IDE are you using? Syntax highlighting and force UTF-8 encoding are basic necessities

Comment: I'm using the Geany editor, and syntax highlighting is enabled, but I wasn't focused for a while... How to force UTF-8 encoding?